# Want to check a single check box on every check box click, flat list any one can help me?

Tags: react-native, checkbox, react-native-flatlist

I have a list of Items along with **Check Box**. I face a problem that when I click on a single check box all the checkboxes are selected. I want to check only those box who I will select.

```
const Items = ({item, index}) => {
    return (
<View style={styles.status}>
          <CheckBox onAnimationType='fill' offAnimationType='fade' boxType='square' disabled={false} 
          onValueChange={()=>{onChangeValue(item, index)}} />
        </View>
);}
```

```
return (
<FlatList
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
        data={students}
        renderItem={Items}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add flag for active checkbox

```js
const sampleData = [{
 text:"data 1",
 active:false
},
{
 text:"data 2",
 active:false
}]

//...

const [checkbox,setCheckbox] = useState(sampleData);

const changeCheckboxFlag = (index)=>{
  setCheckbox((prev)=>{
   const newCheckboxData = prev;
   newCheckboxData[index].active = !newCheckboxData[index].active;
   return newCheckboxData;
  })
}

//...

onValueChange={()=> changeCheckboxFlag(index)
```